# const char* and char[] (char array)

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
  const char *a[] = {"zero","one"};
  char b[] = "zero";
  bool c = b==a[0];
}
```

Why is `bool` value `zero` since I passed the same string and how to make it as `1`?

Comment: You cannot compare strings as simple as that. For this piece of code you'd need [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) function. But better use `std::string`, it that case `b==a[0]` would actually compare strings.

Comment: The address of `b` does not equal the address held by the pointer `a[0]`.

Comment: I think your teacher should see that: https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk title is clickbaity, but talk is great.

Comment: If `b` was declared as `const char* b = "zero";` instead, I guess `c` would be `true`. This is not guaranteed by the language, but most compilers create a *pool of literal strings*. Two identical literal strings *usually* will be merged into a single physical memory address. In the original code, `b` is declared on stack, so its address cannot be the same as a literal string.

Answer (score 5):

`const char *a[] = {"zero","one"};` creates two arrays, one filled with the characters of “zero” followed by a null character, and the other filled with the characters of “one” followed by a null character, and sets `a[0]` to point to the first element of the first array and `a[1]` to point to the first element of the second array.

`char b[] = "zero";` creates an array and fills it with the characters of “zero” followed by a null character.

`b==a[0]` converts the array `b` to a pointer to its first element and compares that pointer to the pointer `a[0]`. Since these point to different arrays, the `==` operation evaluates as false (zero). The fact the two arrays contain the same data is irrelevant. The pointers are compared, not the array contents.

To compare two strings, you can use `std::strcmp`, declared in the header `<cstring>`. `std::strcmp(b, a[0])` returns zero if and only if the two strings are the same. `bool c = std::strcmp(b, a[0]) == 0;` will set `c` to true if and only if the two strings are the same.

(`std::strcmp` returns a negative number if the first string is “less than” the second string, where “less than” means the first position that differs has a lower character code in the first string than in the second string, taking the characters as `unsigned char` values. It returns a positive number if the first string is greater than the second string.)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `==` on `char*` or any other pointers, in C++, you test whether the two pointers are pointing to the same object.

`a[0]` and `b` are pointing to different characters. So, the result will be false.

If you want to compare the content, you need to use `strcmp` or, better, use `std::string` and use `==` on them.

P.S.: I skipped over the part where the char array decays into a pointer. You can come back to this concept later.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, what you are doing is not comparing two strings, but comparing two addresses.
When you are comparing b with a[0], it starts comparing their addresses, address meaning the physical address where the value is residing in memory which are obviously different, that is why it returns 0.

what you need is strcmp function, it takes 2 character pointers and returns whether the strings themselves are same/equal or not.

Comment: Minor pedantic nit:  comparing the **address of `b`** against the **pointer held in the variable `a[0]`**.  Not comparing the address of `a[0]` itself.